# Laravel Has Many Returns a Row even it has a value in relations table

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I'm using laravel eloquent for my database query. My Problem is that I can't show the data I wanted to show. I have three tables. Say Users Table, Roles Table and User_Roles table.

**Users**

*id | Name |*

1  | John |

2  | Doe  |

**Roles**

*id | Name |*

1  | Admin |

2  | Employee |

3  | Manager |

**User_Roles**

*id | user_id | role_id*

1  | 1       | 2

2  | 1       | 3

3  | 2       | 3

Users has Many Roles that is saved in User_Roles table. My query is "I want to show list of Users that has no Employee roles. In the table I want to show only Doe. How can I make it laravel eloquent.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `roles` relation in `User` model

```
public function roles() {
    retrun $this->belongsToMany(\Namespace\Role::class);
}
```

Retrive the role

```
$role = \Namespace\Role::where('name', 'Employee')->first();
```

Get the users

```
$user = \Namespace\User::whereHas('roles', function($query) use ($role) {
    $query->where('role_id', '!=', $role->id);
})->get();
```